# read text file that has repeating blocks of data in matlab

Tags: matlab, text-files

I have a text file of the following form:

...

```
           3
  x=         0.10000   3    s
A      -1.554489099     -6.345000000      0.55574511
A       6.346000000     -0.134800000      4.45454546
V      -1.666613300     -6.333453600     -2.11111145
           3
  x=         0.20000   3    s
A       7.777755558     -4.033333330     -5.323232323
A       8.122322238     -5.007007007      2.045467754
V      -2.443366723     -5.222333337     -6.868889099
           3
```

...

the first line is mostly spaces and a number, the second line has a variable I want to aggregate (x=some number), and ignore the rest of the line,  and the next 3 lines have all variables I also want to aggregate in an array form (the A,A,V), and this repeats again and again.

I would like to read this text file such that I will have a vector (1xn) for `x` values, and a 3D array (3x3xn) for the A,A,V values as function of x.

What I have tried is to read line by line using `fgetl(fid)` but this gives me for each line a vector of char that I can't work with. I've also tried `dlmread` but the file structure doesn't work here.

How can I read such a text file in a form that I can use?

Comment: Why can't you work with a vector of chars?

Comment: it's a long vector with spaces that capture the entire line, and I was hoping to see how this can be handled , or broken apart according to the content... I wasn't able to solve it.

Comment: I still don't see why you can't use it. Maybe you don't know about [strsplit()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html)?

Comment: because I never heard of strsplit ...

Answer (score 1):

So with the help of `strsplit` this is the solution I've got:
(if there is something better I can do please let me know)

```
fid = fopen(fn);
n=0;
while true  
    tline = fgetl(fid);
        if ~ischar(tline); break; end   %end of file
   n=n+1;
   c{n}=strsplit(tline);
end


Names={c{3}{1},c{4}{1},c{5}{1}}; % the A A V

k=0;
for n=2:5:numel(c)
    k=k+1;    
    x(k)=str2num(c{n}{3});
    for j=1:numel(Names)
       AAV(j,:,k)=  cell2mat(cellfun(@str2num,c{n+j}(2:4),'un',0));
    end
end
```